# AWS EC2リージョン移転について

Tags: aws

現在アメリカ バージニア州でEC2を作成し、WEBサイトを構築したんですが、リージョンが近い方がレスポンスが明らかに速いので東京へ移行したいと思っています。

スナップショットとという単語を初めて聞く初心者なのですが、スナップショットは要するにディスクコピーですよね？

EC2でsshを立ち上げApacheやPHP、MYSQLなどインストールした時、またワードプレスで書いた記事やアップロードした画像のデータは全てEBSに保存されているのならスナップショットを取って、東京リージョン間へコピーし、右上のリージョン設定から東京を選択し、インスタンスを新しく作成、その際EBSを先ほどコピーしたスナップショットにすれば、綺麗に移転できますか？

この時、東京とアメリカの二つのインスタンスの唯一の違いはグローバルIPアドレスだけで、ドメイン登録、再度DNS設定するだけで完全移行できますか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

スナップショットと言う用語はVMWareやHyper-Vの様なオンプレミスの仮想OSでも普通に使われます。仮想OSの現在の状態を保存して、容易に保存した状態を復元あるいは複製するための物です。

Amazon EC2で同じ仮想マシンを複製する場合にはSnapShotではなくAMIを使用します。

1. 対象インスタンスを選択してアクションからイメージの作成を使ってAMIを作成します。
2. イメージのAMIに作成したイメージが登録されるので、AMIを選択してAMIのコピーを実行し、移行先リージョンに複製します。
3. 新しくインスタンスを作りたいリージョンに移動した後、インスタンスの作成にてMyイメージを開くと、先ほど作成したAMIが表示されるので選択します。

このような手順でインスタンスを作成すると、全く同じ内容のコピーを作成できます。

Comment: 予想以上に簡単にできました。エラーもありませんでした。